# Identify if a message is already read in Azure Service Bus Topic

Tags: azure, service, azure-servicebus-topics, bus

I have 65k records in Azure Service Bus Topic, while testing, whenever my test application is started, it reads all the 65k records. Can you please help me how can we avoid reading messages that have already read or How can we read only the messages that are send after executing test application?

Answer (score 2):

From the question, it's unclear what exactly you're after. Here are a few things for consideration.

Queues/subscriptions are intended to be read by the consumers, not to store messages and access conditionally. To avoid consuming messages, you should consume those either by using `ReceiveAndDelete` receiving more, or `PeekLock` and completing the received messages.

If these messages are test messages and are not intended for the production, do not mix the environments and use different namespaces.

Alternatively, set a short `TimeToLive` on your test messages to get rid of those. You could also drop the entity and recreate it, but I try to avoid this if your performing testing quite often.